# '.NET 7: A public method named 'ConfigureProduction' or 'Configure' could not be found in the 'Program' type.'

Tags: c#, flutter, dart, asp.net-core

i have this kind of prob, i want integrate Flutter with .Net core web API. I'm new to flutter so, i just followed the tutorial, i want connect localhost to flutter using real device but i got an error when put this  code in program.cs

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
  .UseKestrel()
  .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
  .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000", "http://192.168.0.243:5000")
  .UseIISIntegration()
  .UseStartup<Program>()
  .Build();
```

i change variable in UseStartup<> from Startup to program because startup.cs was removed in .NET 7. how to solve this?

Comment: Well if you're going to use a startup class, it needs to comply with the startup requirements. It sounds like yours didn't. The bigger question is why you believe you *need* to use a startup class... what do you want to do there that you can't do directly when building? And if there *are* things that you need a startup class for, is there any reason you can't create one?

Comment: Try this `http://0.0.0.0:5000`.

Comment: The `Startup` class was not removed, it is just not the default anymore. You still need to register your services and middlewares somehow. If you already had it working with a `Startup` class you could just restore the file, or you could look into "ASP.Net Core Minimal API" and redo it the new way.